# What genre is "The Uplifting News Channel" by Dredg?

Tags: rock, identify-this-genre

Surfing on the internet I came across [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6wnyv8Cp9U) song (Dredg - The Uplifting News Channel) which I really liked. I looked up the group on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dredg) and I was wondering what rock genre they correspond to, and especially that song. I was thinking something like "progressive rock" or "experimental" but I'm not sure.

Comment: Peterix, did you like one of the answers below? In this case you could accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Progressive is also correct but pretty generic, the styles dredg play are usually referred as Crossover Prog (a prog combination of alternative style with indie elements) and Post/Math/Experimental. "Canyon Behind Her" was the first Dredg song I heard and I really liked it.

Here are some definitions from [Progarchives](http://www.progarchives.com):

- [Crossover Prog](http://www.progarchives.com/subgenre.asp?style=3)
- [Post Rock/Math Rock](http://www.progarchives.com/subgenre.asp?style=32)

About [Dredg](http://www.progarchives.com/artist.asp?id=1814):

> **Crossover Prog** ( . . . ) They **transcend many genres with their art-rock styles** and manage to be one of the deepest and most talented **modern progressive bands** today.

Answer (score 1):

The wikipedia article offers a set of categories, but they all point to the genre not being standard rock or metal.  "Genre" for me is a bit of a slippery thing because many bands are not straight down the middle of any particular genre, even in a single song.  So for example with this song: it's (a bonus track) from an album that included artwork which contained clues for a treasure hunt :  it's hard-driving like metal, but there are lighter touches in parts of the song with a small hint of a reggae beat at one point. Already that's quite a few alternative, arty , diverse influences. For me a better description would be something that says this song isn't in a particular category or genre, so maybe
 "rock with diverse interests".